# Syntax Question IF ELSE (Java)

Tags: java

what is the java syntax for saying

if x is not equal to a or b

I am trying to write an if else statement .. if a certain value is not equal to say 2 or 3 then do something else do something else :) thats confusing lol

Comment: I think this is more of a semantics question that a syntax question.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
if (x != a && x != b) {
  // Something (action x)
} else {
  // Something else (action y)
}
```

Note that it's an "and" condition even though you're asking whether x is equal to a *or* b because each condition is negative. The other way you could represent this (if you find it more readable) is:

```
if (!(x == a || x == b)) {
  // Something (action x)
} else {
  // Something else (action y)
}
```

And at that point you *may* find it more readable still to get rid of the negation, but switch round what you do in the blocks:

```
if (x == a || x == b) {
  // Action y
} else {
  // Action x
}
```

These three blocks of code all do the same thing, but I think I'd find the bottom one the most readable as the condition is simple.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( x != a && x != b )
```

Notice it's an &&, not an ||

The condition `( x != 2 || x != 3 )` is *always* true: if x = 2, then x != 3 and the condition is true. if x = 1, then x != 2 and the condition is true.

What you're really saying is: if x is not one of 2 or 3, which is, x is not in the array [2,3], which is "x is not 2 neither 3", which is `x != 2 and x != 3`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((x != a) && (x != b)) {
    // do stuff
} else {
    // do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

directly mimics the english sentence: if x is not equal to a or b

```
if (!(x == a || x == b))
{
    doSomething();
}
else
{
    somethingElse();
}
```

but if the extra not operator and parentheses hurts your eyes, use this(note the absence of the word Or in this condition, not anymore parallel with english sentence):

```
if (x != a && x != b) 
{
    doSomething();
}
else
{
    somethingElse();
}
```

see my answer on [programmer's ignorance pet peeve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423823/whats-your-favorite-programmer-ignorance-pet-peeve/423939#423939) and [Is it acceptable to only use the ‘else’ portion of an ‘if-else’ statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473392/is-it-acceptable-to-only-use-the-else-portion-of-an-if-else-statement/1475135#1475135), why i advocate constructing simple conditions(directly mimics english sentence, i.e. without sticky ANDs and too much NOTs)

Comment: It's advisable to include the curly braces even though they are technically optional on one liners. Let's set a good example for the noobs.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(x!=a && x!=b){
  //do...
}
```

Comment: Uppercase variable names is not recommended in Java.

Comment: @Asaph: as if *that* is the problem

Comment: @Asaph: They may be constants. More worrying is the fact that the condition is wrong... it should be an "and" rather than an "or".

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, corrected the answer. Think i  need some sleep.

Answer (score -2):

in java if-else is a control statement which is used to test condition and transfer the control based on the evolution of condition.

```
if((x!='a')||(x!='b'))//if a,b is char use quotes else avoid
 {
        //if expression is true
 }
else
 {
      //if expression is false
 }
```

if you want that code should be executed when x=a and x=b both then use '&&' instead of '||'.

For more details:

http://java.meritcampus.com/t/60/If-else-if-ladder?tc=mm70

Comment: I'm not sure this adds anything to the existing answers.

Comment: Not only that, but it's completely wrong - the expression is true whenever `x` is not equal to *both* `a` and `b`.  That's unlikely if `a!=b`.