# I am using if/else wrong

Tags: java, android, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Syntax Question IF ELSE (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496435/syntax-question-if-else-java)

I am trying to make a calculator which shows a message if no value is entered in editbox. But it FC's!! I am making apps after long time so I am quite confused.

```
private OnClickListener startListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {               
        double a=0;
        double b=0;
        double c=0;
        EditText edit;
        EditText edit2;
        TextView edit3;
        String lname="";
        edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
        edit2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit2);
        edit3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.edit3); // everything defined above


        String editstr= edit.getText().toString(); // real work starts
        if(editstr.contentEquals(lname))
            edit3.setText("Enter value");
        else

        a=Double.parseDouble(edit.getText().toString()); // else add the stuff
        b=Double.parseDouble(edit2.getText().toString());
        c=a+b;
        edit3.setText(Double.toString(c));

    } };
```

Comment: It is always better to use { } to define block of code. if() {} else {}

Comment: Edited title to not blame broken code on the programming language.

Comment: just correct my code..i can learn

Comment: It is also a good idea to use a code formatter, preferably an IDE that continuously formats the code. At a minimum, if it is not doing what you expect, run it through a formatter.

Comment: `just correct my code..i can learn`. **Reading the manual** is the first step.

Comment: IMHO, using braces *every* time makes the code easier to read, even for "one  liners".  It makes no difference to the compiler.

Comment: @Simon: as long as you avoid the brackets on same line (egyptian brackets) which i just editted out. no formatting and those = pain.

Comment: @Shark If you don't like answering questions then why even be on SO? This may be an elementary question to you but there is no need to criticize the OP for a stupid question. We all had to start learning somewhere.

Comment: @Tom.  Yes and no.  Problem is, if SO answers every single question that should rightfully be done in programming 101/Hello World/read the tutorial (and thereby not reinforcing the behaviour we all want to encourage), the signal to noise ratio will get so low that the people who truly can contribute will stop coming.  Not answering and closing low value questions is necessary to keep SO healthy IMHO

Comment: I agree. But no need to do it in a way that derides the questioner or suggests that we're not willing to help on legitimate questions.

Comment: @Tom This is the sorta shit one should ask their classmates IMHO. It's not a legitimate question saying "my if/else don't work, heres my code you can fix". There is ZERO effort involved here. It even took two people to format his own code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put brackets around your if-else, currently in case of else it only executes the first line, other lines are executed no matter if your if passes or fails.

```
if(editstr.contentEquals(lname)) {
    edit3.setText("Enter value");
} else {
    a=Double.parseDouble(edit.getText().toString()); // else add the stuff
    b=Double.parseDouble(edit2.getText().toString());
    c=a+b;
    edit3.setText(Double.toString(c));
}
```

Comment: suggest use of `isEmpty()` or `equals(new String())`

Comment: @Shark actually i tought contentEquals() is a custom method.. :)

Comment: I did too, but String doesn't have it. I suspected that to be the culprit of the broken 'if'.

Comment: @NamanArora you are welcome, and if you are just checking editStr is equals to lName you can use String.equals() instead.

Comment: Actually yo should use .isEmpty() to check for emptyness as that returns true for 'whitespace' strings. Use equals() to compare them, or equalsIgnoreCase() to compare them in a lower-case fashion.

Answer (score 0):

As written, only the `a=Double.parseDouble(edit.getText().toString());` is affected by the else.  If you want the rest of it there, surround the block in `{}`

Answer (score 0):

It does work, it just never fires.

You should do

```
 if(editStr.isEmpty())
     editStr = "Enter value";
 else
 {
    //editStr.equals("someValue"); //test against some value
    //rest
 }
```