# How can the "AND" and "OR" key word used together in a select query?

Tags: mysql

T have a select query as

```
 SELECT * FROM tbl_docuserstatus WHERE doc_id='1' 
AND doc_midlvluser = '1' AND 
(docstatus_id != '4' OR docstatus_id != '5' OR docstatus_id != '8' OR docstatus_id != '0')
```

but the result doesnt seems to be operable for `(docstatus_id != '4' OR docstatus_id != '5' OR docstatus_id != '8' OR docstatus_id != '0')` part.

I need the query to work as display all the values whose docid = 1 and  doc_midlvluser = 1 and dostatus_id shld not be equal to 4 or 5 or 8 or 0

Please help me How it should b used?

Comment: The question is what you're expecting. I have no idea if this works as you need it, since you do not tell us how it should behave! There is no syntax error in there, so you need to give us some more information!

Comment: Learn some boolean algebra. Not only it's interesting, it also helps tons when programming (basically, every time you have a condition).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_docuserstatus WHERE doc_id='1' 
AND doc_midlvluser = '1' AND 
(docstatus_id != '4' AND docstatus_id != '5' 
 AND docstatus_id != '8' AND docstatus_id != '0')
```

Or just apply DeMorgan theorem, so it's easier to code and read:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_docuserstatus WHERE doc_id='1' 
AND doc_midlvluser = '1' AND 
NOT (docstatus_id = '4' OR docstatus_id = '5' 
     OR docstatus_id = '8' OR docstatus_id = '0')
```

Or better yet, use IN:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_docuserstatus WHERE doc_id='1' 
AND doc_midlvluser = '1' AND 
   docstatus_id NOT IN ('4','5','8','0')
```

Related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130965/what-is-the-worst-code-youve-ever-written/311377#311377

And this: [Is it acceptable to only use the 'else' portion of an 'if-else' statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473392/is-it-acceptable-to-only-use-the-else-portion-of-an-if-else-statement/1475135#1475135)

Answer (score 0):

Your OR clause is mutually exclusive:

if docstatus_id = 4, then it is not valid according to the first part of the clause, but IS valid on the rest.

perhaps you should use docstatus_id not in ('4','5','8','0') if that's what you are trying to achieve.